# Multiple button click event in jQuery which are created in loop

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

Here the buttons are created in loop means the numbers of countries and buttons will be same.
Now I want click event of every button as per its id and also the id of respective `input textboxes`.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.countries) {   
  var textId = item.Name+"_text";            
  var cnt = item.Name;              
    <td><label class="control-label" >@item.Name</label></td>                                              
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)</td>
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryId, new { @Value = item.ID })</td>
    <td><input type="text" id=@textId /></td>            
    <td><button type="button" class="btn-primary" id=@cnt>Update</button></td>               
}
```

Comment: this is not look like jquery..plz tag your framework so that people can understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I follow but in order to get the id inside the click handler you could do this

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function(){
   var buttonId = this.id;
   // the rest of the code
})
```

Comment: One more thing..If the id is "United State" then its showing only "United".Can you please help that I can get whole string.

Comment: An id with white spaces is not valid, you'll need to replace white spaces by (for instance) "_".

Comment: If I want id of the textbox as written in question code then what should I do in button click function?

Comment: @user3206357: is every iteration of the `foreach` a different row? I don't see any code to create `tr` tags but wanted to check if you missed to show some code.

Comment: Yes..in foreach loop every time a new row created and in every row one label of country,textboxes and a update button created.

Answer (score 2):

To use dynamic elements on

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click',function(){
  var Id = $(this).attr("id");
})
```